# Manage my Pinterest without giving them my password?

Tags: pinterest

Quite a simple question really although I can't seem to find an answer. I have a few interns helping me out with my social media and I can give them the necessary access to what they need via apps sch as hootsuite. Unfortunately I can't find anything that works with Pinterest and I'd rather not hand over my password to log in. Any ideas how they could manage it* without having direct access?

*post new pins, repin etc.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only solution is to make shared boards and add them as contributors. then they can contribute to board without being the board's admin. but the pins will be under their name. this is most used by businesses to maintain an active Pinterest account.